# Adding a deathrattle to a card that already has one

Tags: hearthstone

Suppose I have a card with a deathrattle, such as [Cairne Bloodhoof](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/498-cairne-bloodhoof). What happens if I use a card that gives a minion a deathrattle, [Ancestral Spirit](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/526-ancestral-spirit), to the minion?

I can see two possibilities:

- The minion's deathrattle is replaced
- The minion is given an additional deathrattle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Hearthstone Wiki](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Deathrattle): Minions may benefit from multiple Deathrattles at the same time.

In your example, Cairne's bloodrattle would go off first, summoning the 4/5 Baine.  After that, Ancestral Spirit would resummon Cairne.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kexlox' answer: there is already a minion with two deathrattles: Anub'arak. When it dies, it is returned to your hand *and* a 4/4 Nerubian is summoned. So if this minion has already two deathrattles, it can be expected that all minions can have multiple.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that just a single deathrattle with two effects?

Comment: I suppose it might come down to semantics as it really has no bearing one way or the other, but I would definitely consider that a single Deathrattle effect as there is only a single "Deathrattle" keyword. There is no precedent for a card coming stock with two Deathrattle effects, likely because there is no appreciable difference whether it's two effects or one with multiple interactions.