# Can Unearthed Raptor copy multiple deathrattle effects?

Tags: hearthstone

According to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248474/adding-a-deathrattle-to-a-card-that-already-has-one), a card can receive an extra deathrattle effect from cards like Ancestral Spirit. The battlecry for [Unearthed Raptor](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/27220-unearthed-raptor) reads:

> Choose a friendly minion. Gain a copy of its Deathrattle effect.

What if the target has multiple deathrattles? Does it copy both deathrattle effects?

Note that I'm not talking about doubling its battlecry effect using [Brann Bronzebeard](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/27214-brann-bronzebeard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can copy multiple Deathrattle effects.

I saw a video of 1 Raptor filling one side of the field with cards after dying because of multiple copied effects (combination with Bran, Brewmaster and Faceless)

Comment: If someone could add the video in embedded form feel free to edit it in

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can.

In fact it can copy up to 16 deathrattle effects.

Source:

[Twitter](http://www.twitter.com/playhearthstone/status/667946006315532288) - Thanks Rob

Comment: Do you have a source (or calculation) for the exact number?

Comment: @AverageUnknown Here is the source for the exact number: https://twitter.com/playhearthstone/status/667946006315532288